# Android database crashing

Tags: java, android, database, crash, rss

I am new to Android Development and was making an app that can read an rss xml file, store it in a database and be accessible locally. As I was doing this, the code was crashing and I can't figure out why. I have tried some things but am getting nowhere. I would really appreciate any help. Thank You

**LayoutFile (maintwo.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I&apos;m screen 2 (main2.xml)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity File (ActivityTwo.java)**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ActivityTwo extends Activity{

    //private DatabaseHelper helper;
    private TextView tv;
    private ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    private HandleXML handleXML;
    //DatabaseHelper helper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maintwo);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        //storeToDB();
        //writeToFile();
        getFromXML();
    }
    /*public void storeToDB() {
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        helper.insertContact("Something", "123");
        helper.insertContact("Another", "456");
    }
    public void writeToFile() {
        strings = helper.getAllContacts();
        String x = strings.get(0);
        String y = strings.get(2);
        tv.setText(x + " " + y);
    }*/
    public void getFromXML() {
        handleXML = new HandleXML("http://examplewebsite/file.xml");
        handleXML.fetchXML();
        strings = handleXML.getAll();
        //strings = helper.getAllContacts();
        String x = strings.get(0);
        tv.setText(x);
    }
}
```

**RSS Reader (HandleXML.java)**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class HandleXML extends Activity{

    private String title = "title";
    private String link = "link";
    private String description = "description";
    private DatabaseHelper helper;

    private String urlString = null;
    private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
    public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
    public HandleXML(String url){
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        this.urlString = url;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getAll() {
        return helper.getAllContacts();
    }
    /*public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public String getLink(){
        return link;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }*/
    public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        int i =0;
        String text=null;
        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType();
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name=myParser.getName();
                switch (event){
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = myParser.getText();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if(name.equals("title")){
                            title = text;
                        }
                        else if(name.equals("link")){
                            link = text;
                        }
                        else if(name.equals("description")){
                            description = text;
                        }
                        else{
                        }
                        break;
                }
                helper.insertContact(title + i, "123");
                i++;
                event = myParser.next();
            }
            parsingComplete = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void fetchXML(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    myparser.setInput(stream, null);
                    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                    stream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

**File used to create db (DatabaseHelper.java)**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
    public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";

    private HashMap hp;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table contacts " + "(id integer primary key, name text,phone text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertContact  (String name, String phone)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("name", name);
        contentValues.put("phone", phone);

        db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor getData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null );
        return res;
    }

    public int numberOfRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);
        return numRows;
    }

    public boolean updateContact (Integer id, String name, String phone)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);
        contentValues.put("phone", phone);
        db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteContact (Integer id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("contacts",
                "id = ? ",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }

    public ArrayList getAllContacts()
    {
        ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
        res.moveToFirst();
        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
}
```

**Crash Report**

```
01-23 20:33:10.124  19847-19847/com.varvaniweb.example.helloworld E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.varvaniweb.example.helloworld, PID: 19847
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.varvaniweb.example.helloworld/com.varvaniweb.example.helloworld.ActivityTwo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:256)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
            at com.varvaniweb.example.helloworld.DatabaseHelper.getAllContacts(DatabaseHelper.java:87)
            at com.varvaniweb.example.helloworld.HandleXML.getAll(HandleXML.java:33)
            at com.varvaniweb.example.helloworld.ActivityTwo.getFromXML(ActivityTwo.java:45)
            at com.varvaniweb.example.helloworld.ActivityTwo.onCreate(ActivityTwo.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating an `Activity` yourself (`HandleXML`) and using that as the `context` needed by your `DatabaseHelper`:

```
handleXML = new HandleXML("http://examplewebsite/file.xml");
```

Inside HandleXML:

```
public HandleXML(String url) {
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this); // <-- PROBLEM: this does not have Context info
    this.urlString = url;
}
```

You should **never** be instantiating application components yourself. It is the system's responsibility to do so -- and as part of doing that, the system attaches information about the app and the component that it is creating on your behalf. Because you created it yourself, it doesn't have the necessary `Context` information to open a database (or do much of anything, really).

Change your HandleXML class so that it does not extend Activity and is instead given a Context to pass to the DatabaseHelper:

```
public class HandleXML {
    ...
    public HandleXML(Context context, String url) {
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        this.urlString = url;
    }
    ...
}
```

Call it in your `ActivityTwo` like this:

```
handleXML = new HandleXML(this, "http://examplewebsite/file.xml");
```